# How to set manually the alternate file

Tags: register, multiple-files, alternate-file

Reading the documentation about alternate file, I thought I could manipulate `#` like a global variable, but it's not the case. I was thinking doing something like

```
let &#='/path/to/alternate/file'
```

Which is not possible.

How would you set manually the alternate file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The alternate file is stored in a register, `"#`. Change you line to:

```
let @#='/path/to/alternate/file'
```

For more help see:

```
:h registers
:h quote#
:h :let-@
```